# Is there a wat to set Chromium browsers (edge and chrome) profile name when launching browser with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-chromium

I am using multiple profiles and hence want to give each a unique name so I can identify them quickly. So is there any way to launch a browser with a custom Profile name?

here is how I am launching the browser now.

```
new DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new EdgeConfig());

                    EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
                    options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");

                    options.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
                    options.AddArguments("enable-strict-powerful-feature-restrictions");
                    options.AddArguments("disable-geolocation");
                    options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
                    options.AddArgument(@$"user-data-dir=MyDataDirectoryPath");
                    options.AddArgument(@$"profile-directory=MyProfileDirectory");



                    options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.All);

                    var driverService = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(applicattionSettings.Settings.EdgeDriverPath);
                    driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

                    Driver = new EdgeDriver(driverService, options);
```

When I launch the browser from the above code default profile name is Profile 1, Profile 2, etc, and I want to change it.

Note: for the chrome browser, I have written a code to navigate to `chrome://settings/manageProfile` find the input field on the page, and change the name and it's working fine.

here is the code.

```
driver.SwitchTo().NewWindow(WindowType.Tab);
                DelayHelper.ActionDelayInSec(1, 1, cancellationToken);
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("chrome://settings/manageProfile");


                IWebElement inputField = (WebElement)driver.ExecuteScript("return document.querySelector('settings-ui').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-main').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-basic-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-section > settings-people-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-animated-pages').querySelector('settings-subpage').querySelector('settings-manage-profile').shadowRoot.querySelector('cr-input').shadowRoot.getElementById('input')"); ;
                
                inputField.Clear();
                inputField.SendKeys(email);
                inputField.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

I want to achieve the same for Edge browser but the problem is Edge browser does not have an input field directly on the page, I have to click the Context menu then click the edit icon and the popup with the input field opened, I tried to do that, but I think it's not possible to click context menu. so I want to know if is there any option to pass when launching the browser that helps change the browser name.?

Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's been no such option to specify your custom profile names yet.

Actually, the context menu can be interacted with via keyboard input. Here're some ideas on how to get into that "Edit" menu after "More actions" (···) has been clicked:

1. Double `Enter` key presses.
2. A single "e" press.

These are all tested in the normal Microsoft Edge instances. Ideally, their relevant automation code should be:

1. Double `Enter` key presses.

   ```
   driver.Url = "edge://settings/profiles";
   IWebElement clickable = driver.FindElement(By.Id("currentProfileOverflowButton"));
        new Actions(driver)
            .Click(clickable)
            .SendKeys(Keys.Enter)
            .SendKeys(Keys.Enter)
            .Perform();
   ```
2. A single "e" press.

   ```
   driver.Url = "edge://settings/profiles";   
   IWebElement clickable = driver.FindElement(By.Id("currentProfileOverflowButton"));
        new Actions(driver)
            .Click(clickable)
            .SendKeys("e")
            .Perform();
   ```

You can have a try and see whether it works for you.

**UPDATE**

After an investigation, I've found out that it is not possible to interact with the flyout menu after you click the More actions (···) with the webdriver because it is even not recognizable. I'll give you an example to show you why.

```
driver.Url = "edge://settings/profiles";   
IWebElement clickable = driver.FindElement(By.Id("currentProfileOverflowButton"));
     new Actions(driver)
         .Pause(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
         .Click(clickable)
         .Pause(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
         .SendKeys(Keys.Tab)
         .Perform();
```

This example simulates the user clicks the More actions (···) and then presses `TAB`. If we **directly** do this in Edge, you'll notice that `TAB` does not work at all because now the focus is on the flyout menu (but it also does not work in the flyout menu unfortunately).

But if we let the **webdriver** do the same thing, you'll notice that after the flyout menu is called, `TAB` works and switches focus to another option in the settings. It can well demonstrate that the webdriver fails to recognize the flyout menu. That's why we stuck at selecting "Edit".

Now, you can choose to create these profiles with customized names first, and then specify the profile path in each automation project. Or you can send feedback to Selenium Team to request a native API editing profile names. You may go to [GitHub Selenium Issues](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues) to seek such support.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input, That could be a possible solution. and it does work manually but not from code. I have tried both your solutions of double pressing enter or pressing e once. I also tried adding a delay between the click and pressing the key, but nothing seems to be working.

I think the key is going on the context menu because, on the key press, it gets focused like it's selected. I have tried to move focus on the body element and then pressing the key but that as well didn't work.

what do you think could be the issue here?

Comment: Hi @ZubairKhakwani, I've had an investigation and updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: thanks for the update, actually I have found a solution, there is a AddUserProfilePreference method in EdgeOptions class if we pass it profile.name as key and any value, it changes the profile name but only for default profile, it works if we don't use multiple profiles within a same folder which is achieved using profile-directory argument, luckely I am already using user-data-dir argument to create separate directory for each of my profile so I removed profile-directory argument. but still, if we found a way to change preference of profile-directory it can help in the future. any suggestion?

Comment: also after testing a little more AddUserProfilePreference for default profile also only works if it's launching for first time, means if I first launch a browser without setting profile name in AddUserProfilePreference and now if I set profile name and run it again it won't work.

Comment: also created an issue according to findings. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11723, your comment on the issue may help.

Comment: Emm, so for now native APIs still don't meet such need quite well. Before you get any useful information or update from developers, my suggestion would be creating those profiles with customized names first. If so, you can also reuse these profiles in the future.

Comment: Actually, it is working now using AddUserProfilePreference and AddLocalStatePreference methods, in my case the issue is that I was passing a key to this method which contains a dot. e.g my.name so it was setting preference for my { name : "my name"} while I need my.name {  } removing the dot fixes everything.